# Show Post Score Breakdown Early Script

Tags: script

[image: vote breakdown picture]

Allows you to click the vote score and get the break-down just like with the [established user privilege](https://stackapps.com/privileges/established-user). This script does not use the data API but extracts votes from the timeline pages (which makes it a bit slow), thus *it will likely break at the slightest change to that page*.

The tooltip on the breakdown shows the total if summing up two numbers again is too hard.

(I have asked on meta if i can post this and did not get any official reply but demand by some people, also there appears to be [a script with similar functionality](https://stackapps.com/questions/557/votecounts-bookmarklet-to-display-up-down-votes-even-for-rep1k)).

Sorry to not provide a file for download but i am sure you will manage somehow, adjust includes as needed:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           StackOverflow Post Score Breakdown
// @namespace      stackoverflow
// @include        http://*stackoverflow.com/questions*
// @include        http://*.stackexchange.com/questions*
// @include        http://*stackapps.com/questions*
// @include        http://*superuser.com/questions*
// ==/UserScript==

(function ()
{
    var cancelWaiting = false;
    var dictionary = null;
    jq_wait();

    function jq_wait()
    {
        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined')
        {
            window.setTimeout(jq_wait, 100);
        } else
        {
            $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
            window.setTimeout(function () { cancelWaiting = true; }, 5000);
            $(document).ready(setup);
        }
    }

    function loadVotes(/*function()*/onCompletedCallback)
    {
        var qId = document.location.href.match(/[0-9]+(?=\/)/)[0];
        if (qId != 'undefined')
        {
            var timelineUrl = "http://" + document.location.host + "/posts/" + qId + "/timeline";
            $.get(timelineUrl, function (data)
            {
                var tl = document.createElement("tl");
                tl.innerHTML = data;
                var summaries = $(tl).find(".vote-summary");
                dictionary = {};

                //For each day summary
                summaries.each(function (si, se)
                {
                    //Get the first blocks for questions and answers.
                    var cells = $(se).find(".qacell");
                    cells.each(function (ci, ce)
                    {
                        var call = $(ce).find("a")[0].getAttributeNode('onclick').value;
                        var postId = idFromCall(call);
                        if (dictionary[postId] == null)
                        {
                            var array = new Array();
                            array[0] = 0;
                            array[1] = 0;
                            dictionary[postId] = array;
                        }
                        array = dictionary[postId];

                        //Get next sibling which contains the votes
                        var eVoteCounter = $(ce).find(" ~ td")[0];

                        var upMatch = $(eVoteCounter).find(".upvote").html().match(/\+[0-9]+/);
                        if (upMatch != null)
                        {
                            array[0] += parseInt(upMatch[0]);
                        }
                        var downMatch = $(eVoteCounter).find(".downvote").html().match(/-[0-9]+/);
                        if (downMatch != null)
                        {
                            array[1] += parseInt(downMatch[0]);
                        }
                    });
                });
                onCompletedCallback();
            });
        }
    }

    function setup()
    {
        var writeBreakDownToSpan = function (qVoteSpan, id)
        {
            if (dictionary == null)
            {
                qVoteSpan.html("loading...");
                loadVotes(function () { writeBreakDownToSpan(qVoteSpan, id); });
            }
            else
            {
                var array = dictionary[id];
                if (array == null)
                {
                    var qParentAnswer = qVoteSpan.closest(".answer");
                    if (qParentAnswer.length > 0 && qParentAnswer.hasClass("deleted-answer")) return;
                    array = [0, 0];
                }
                var totalScore = array[0] + array[1];
                var up = array[0].toString();
                var down = array[1];
                if (up > 0) up = "+" + up;
                qVoteSpan.html("<div style=\"color: green;\">" + up + "</div><div class=\"vote-count-separator\"></div><div style=\"color: maroon;\">" + down + "</div>");
                qVoteSpan.attr("title", "Total score: " + totalScore);
            }
        }

        $(".vote").each(function (vi, ve)
        {
            var id = $(ve).find("input").attr("value");
            var qVoteSpan = $(ve).find(".vote-count-post");

            qVoteSpan.css("cursor", "pointer");
            qVoteSpan.click(function ()
            {
                writeBreakDownToSpan(qVoteSpan, id);
                qVoteSpan.css("cursor", "");
            });
        });
    }

    function idFromCall(/*string*/input)
    {
        return idFromRev(revFromCall(input));
    }

    function revFromCall(/*string*/input)
    {
        var match = input.match(/'[^']*'/)[0];
        match = match.substring(1, match.length - 1);
        return match;
    }

    function idFromRev(/*string*/input)
    {
        var match = input.match(/rev-[0-9]+(?=-)/)[0].replace(/rev-/, "");
        match = match.substring(0, match.length - 4);
        return match;
    }
})();
```