# "View Vote totals" without 1000 rep

Tags: script, chrome-extensions, greasemonkey, bookmarklet

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

The vote counts are a great tool to determine whether an answer is disputed or not. Unfortunately, not many of us have enough time to join all Stack Exchange websites and get [1000 reputation](https://stackapps.com/privileges/established-user).

This script unlocks the "View Vote counts" feature for those who are not logged in or don't have 1k reputation. The look and feeling of the feature is identical to the original one.

Recognises posts at questions, question lists, `/review/` pages and search results.

#### License

[Creative Commons 3.0 SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) - Same as footer. You may modify and distribute this script <sup>**S**</sup>, provided that you mention the original author of the script <sup>**A**</sup>.

#### Download

The code is available in three forms:

- Chrome extension in the Chrome Web Store, ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-vote-totals-without/oibfliilcglieepgkdkahpfiiigdijdd).
- (Greasemonkey) User script at Greasyfork.org: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/6192-stack-exchange-view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep
- Bookmarklet, for testing without installing: Copy from the user script, starting from "javascript:".

#### Platform

The code is OS-independent. It should at least work in the following browsers:

- Firefox 3.0 - 64
- Opera 9.00 - 12.00
- Chrome 1 - 71
- Internet Explorer 7 - 10
- Edge 12 - 15
- Safari 3.2 - 5.1

### Contact

Please send your feedback to `rob@robwu.nl`.

### Code

This script is written in JavaScript and a bit of jQuery. It depends on the Stack Exchange API (v2, JSONP).

When the *Vote counts* feature is disabled, the *Vote counts* buttons don't have a tooltip. The script checks for the existence of the tooltip, and adds the feature when necessary. If the tooltips already exist, the script does not add any visible modifications to the page.

A detailed explanation of the code is listed in the source code ([direct link](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/6192-stack-exchange-view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep/code/Stack%20Exchange:%20%22View%20Vote%20totals%22%20without%201000%20rep.user.js), or via the [overview page](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/6192-stack-exchange-view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep/code)). The change log is listed at the overview page.

Comment: Seems buggy. Screws with upvote and downvote buttons. Count breaks if you mess with screwed up upvote and downvote buttons. But, it does what it's supposed to... thanks :)

Comment: @GGG I have uploaded a new version, which adds a CSS-fix for IE7-. Do you still observe the bug? If yes, please specify your browser version and OS.

Comment: Yep, it's still messed up. Click the vote count, then click vote up a few times, then click the vote count again. I'm using a somewhat old chromium on a somewhat old ubuntu. 16.0.912.75 (Developer Build 116452 Linux) Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: @GGG Updated and uploaded code. Now, you can also show vote counts after voting. I notice that, after voting, **the SE API does not necessarily show the newest vote counts**. After a few minutes, the requested counts are correct, though. This might be a bug in the SE API.

Comment: It appears to be mostly fixed. There seems to be a problem where it appears to let you remove upvotes after the time for removing them has passed. Of course they aren't actually removed, but have the appearance of being removed. That's pretty trivial though. Nice work :)

Comment: Nice work, Rob! If you wanted, you could save some bytes by omitting `type="text/css"` on the `<style>` element — it’s optional in HTML5 anyway, and it still works in all browsers without.

Comment: Good script. Makes me wonder, if the information is available via the API anyway, then why does SE hide it?

Comment: @user2428118 See Jeff's answer at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1007/169101.

Comment: @RobW Installed it on Chrome 23.0.1271.97 (stable) and it doesn't seem to work at all :(

Comment: @PaulT. Works fine here. If you're trying it in incognito mode, you have to check the tick before "Allow in incognito" at `chrome://extensions/`.

Comment: @RobW My apologies, I didn't realize that you had to click on the counters for the upvotes/downvotes to appear. I assumed it would automatically replace all the counters. But no matter, this is a great extension! Thanks :)

Comment: Took me a minute too @PaulT.

Comment: Just had the thought, I'd certainly like to use an app/script which would alert me to any questions/answers that have been downvoted with no comment given so I could counter it and upvote them since that form of downvoting practice doesn't help out the user who posted the question/answer thus fails to support the community.

Comment: @Myzifer Don't practice pity upvoting, that's harmful. If you get alerted of all downvotes, your computer would explode on Stack Overflow, given the huge volume of questions. Lots has already been said about this topic, just search for "pity upvoting" or ["sympathy upvoting" on meta.stackoverflow.com](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=site:meta.stackoverflow.com+sympathy).

Comment: I wouldn't think of it as pity or sympathy but more re-balancing as such downvotes serve no purpose being there without feedback.

Comment: Nice! Can't believe there were no downvotes though (haha).

Comment: Now you just need to do the same for close votes...     and tag wiki edits. : )

Comment: It seems this doesn't work for Math Overflow : ( .

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS Added Mathoverflow.net to list of sites.

Comment: Will this script be disabled on sites where I have sufficient reputation already?

Comment: @Duncan Yes. See the second-to-last paragraph of the app listing.

Comment: Thanks, @RobW. I read that paragraph but thought it related to whether that feature was enabled (in general) on some smaller sites. More coffee needed.

Comment: Would it be possible for the API url to be switched to https?  This breaks when SSL is used on SE sites.

Comment: @KevinBrown Added https support in v1.5.5.

Comment: People are recommending [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/) as a good UserScripts.org alternative (see [this blogpost](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/05/09/userscripts-org-good-alternatives/) for example).

Comment: Hi, Rob, cool stuff, thx :) Feature-request: include [pt.so] on the list. I did a `*.stackoverflow.com` and removed `meta.stackoverflow.com` to handle this. Cheers!

Comment: Is this even allowed?

Comment: @NarawaGames Yes, this is allowed.

Comment: Area 51 example questions don't work.

Comment: @Fiksdal This was asked before, see my answer at https://stackapps.com/a/4147/9699

Comment: When I first saw this script I assumed it would just show upvotes and downvotes when the page loaded, but it turns out you need to click on the vote count to see them. Even though this is normal for SE I find it kind of counter-intuitive and I'll leave this comment here in case anybody gets stuck.

Comment: The bookmarklet doesn't appear to work in Chromium 61.0.3163.79. Unlike the extension (which works OK), with bookmarklet the three dots blink indefinitely without giving the split.

Comment: @Ruslan Edit the bookmarklet and replace all "http:" with "https:".

Comment: What happens if I have over 1k rep on a site? Does this replace the standard SE mechanism? If so, it would be nice to have the option of a button to show vote counts, so that on sites that I have 1k I can use the default SE, and on the rest I use the separate button. Thanks!

Comment: @CalvT When you have 1k+ rep, the standard SE mechanism is used if available. The script only activates if the vote counter does not appear to support vote totals (detected by the absence of a tooltip on the vote counter).

Comment: Can you please make this a Chrome Extension?

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur There is already a Chrome extension. See the link in the original post.

Comment: @user202729 The script was already supposed to ignore sites where the user has a privilege. But I see that the check is no longer working, I'll fix this with the next update (along with dark theme support).

Answer (score 16):

## Bug Report ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))

- Go to a tag page, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby).
- You will see a question, such as this: [image]
- Find the vote and answer count on the left.
- Click the vote count.
- You will then get a message in the error console that says `Post ID not found! Please report this at http://stackapps.com/q/3082/9699`

So now I'm reporting it.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, I've even forgotten that I've added that link to the error message. Turns out to be useful ;) I'll check it out later.

Comment: Fixed :) The last update (v1.5.3) introduces a feature which is not even available to 1k+ users: View vote totals at the questions list and search results.

Answer (score 8):

**Feature Request**

Can we get a setting to show the counts automatically without clicking?

Comment: Automatically showing up/down votes puts lots of load on the Stack Exchange API, so I'm probably not going to add the feature. Besides, the net vote count is usually the most interesting number. Downvotes are only relevant if you want to see whether the contents of a post are disputed.

Comment: @RobW: Perhaps only show vote count for directly accessed questions (by "direct" I mean excluding question feed)?

Answer (score 8):

## Bug report  ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))

It doesn't work for the new [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

The following `@match` entries in the script:

```
// @match          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match          http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match          http://stackoverflow.com/review/*
// @match          http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/*
// @match          http://stackoverflow.com/search*
// @match          http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search*
```

Should be changed to:

```
// @match          http://*.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match          http://*.stackoverflow.com/review/*
// @match          http://*.stackoverflow.com/search*
```

This will catch SO and SOpt and their respective Meta sites.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I've just updated the extension and uploaded the updated script to Greasyfork: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/6192-stack-exchange-view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep.

Comment: Bravo, spreading the word, I mean, *espalhando a notícia* :)

Answer (score 5):

## Bug Report  ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))

This script is no longer working as of yesterday (12/20/2018) for me on any SE site, it looks like StackExchange redesigned the voting buttons. Clicking on the score of a post now has no effect whatsoever. I'm using Chrome 71 on Windows 10 if it matters.

It looks like this script was broken by the same UI change that made the vote buttons bigger.

New (broken): [image: A screenshot of the new vote buttons] Old: [image: A screenshot of the old buttons]

Comment: yup, so annoying!

Comment: Happens to me too (Chrome, Mac).

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I really missed this script and Rob W [hasn't been around for a month and a half](https://stackexchange.com/users/902274/rob-w?tab=activity). So **I wrote a script myself.  You can find it at https://stackapps.com/questions/8166/view-up-and-down-votes-for-everybody**.

Comment: @BrockAdams I'm still around. I'll look into this, update the script and publish an updated extension.

Comment: @RobW The Chrome extension doesn't look like it's been updated yet.

Comment: @EKons There may be some time (hours) between me publishing and the extension actually updating. The Chrome Web Store listing has been updated, at least.

Comment: Working for me now in Chrome.  Thanks for the quick fix, @RobW!

Comment: @RobW I can confirm that the userscript is working again, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
Is it possible to view vote counts on Area51 proposal questions?
It would be helpful to see where the followers are being stingy with each other, and then open a question to discuss it.

Comment: No, because the Stack Exchange API does not have any information about area51: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=99999&filter=!*L6X1NvG5lnyyK4-&run=true

Comment: Darn, that's too bad.

Comment: If enough people upvote (*hint, hint*) [the related feature request](http://stackapps.com/questions/6226/are-there-plans-to-involve-area51-in-se-api-version-3) and [supporting posts](http://stackapps.com/questions/linked/4590?sort=votes), then they *have* to add Area51 support. Right? Right!? (^_^)

Comment: I guess 1000 rep doesn't work there, then. That is unfair, although separate vote counts there aren't the immediate need.

Answer (score 4):

## Bug report  ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))

When the new beta dark mode on Stack Overflow is enabled, the colors have poor contrast. Of course they are still fine in the usual light mode.

[image]

Comment: I've fixed this in the latest update. The user script has been updated, the Chrome extension is pending review approval.

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Use the true minus sign, not the hyphen:

```patch
--- current
+++ fixed
@@ -174,7 +174,7 @@
                 json = json.items[0];
                 var up = json.up_vote_count, down = json.down_vote_count;
                 up = up ? '+' + up : 0;       /* If up > 0, prefix a plus sign*/
-                down = down ? '-' + down : 0; /* If down > 0, prefix a minus sign */
+                down = down ? '−' + down : 0; /* If down > 0, prefix a minus sign */
                 $this.parent().find('.message-error').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                     $(this).remove();
                 });
```

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

After [the colors change announced on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched?cb=1), the vote totals don't have much color. Compare, for example, StackApps (with the userscript)

> [image]

To MSE (where I have enough rep)

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

## Feature Request

Can you include new images for this script?

[image: Like this]

Comment: Which new images? The script itself does not have any images. Or do you mean the screenshot? I'll leave it at the current state since it is still recognizable.

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

If you show the vote count, then vote on the post, it will change back to just showing the net count and you need to reload to get the vote count again.