# Are there plans to involve Area51 in SE API version 3?

Tags: feature-request, api, area51

Several applications come to mind, proposal publicity, question analysis, making resources files, but I can't find any SE API calls that can do this.

Comment: Perennial question. [The last official answer](http://stackapps.com/a/4591/7653) (`"No... it's different... currently no plans"`) is unlikely to change.

Comment: according to the link, there are no plans to make an Area51 API. so how is Area51 written then? Surely all that is needed is to extract the existing API and polish it for general release?

Comment: I was able to scrape the raw HTML and parse it.

Comment: Area51 is/isn't getting replaced by Prompt Design/GenAI depending on which Meta post you believe. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390571/are-you-interested-in-prompt-design-join-the-community-stakeholders-group ::::::: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390463/starting-the-prompt-design-site-a-new-home-in-our-stack-exchange-neighborhood @TheEmptyStringPhotographer

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer; so they might offer a few API's while they're at it. We live in hope!