# View up and down votes, for everybody

Tags: script, tampermonkey, posts, voting

#### About:

This userscript lets everybody **view the up and down vote counts on a question or answer** -- whether or not they have [the "Established User" privilege](https://stackapps.com/help/privileges/established-user).

It replaces [Rob W's old script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep), <del>which was broken by changes to the Stack Exchange layouts</del>.
Update:  Rob W has now fixed his script.

With the script installed, merely click on a score.  Then ***all*** of the posts on that page will have their up-votes and down-votes shown.

#### Features:

- Shows vote splits for all posts (a question and all it's answers on the current page) with one click. It's convenient and still only takes 1 API call.
- Adds appropriate mouse cues and hover text (`title` attribute).
- Has full API error handling.
- Open source and hosted on GitHub.
- Written from scratch to take advantage of newer features.
- Works everywhere except Area 51, because [Area 51 has no API support](https://stackapps.com/questions/4590/is-there-any-support-for-area-51-in-the-new-api).

#### Here's what it looks like in action:

[image: Animated screen grab of script in action]

#### Download / Install:

This is a userscript that runs in your browser.  It requires a userscript engine like Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey.  <sup><sub>(Greasemonkey 4+ is not recommended nor supported, but it *probably* works with that too.)</sub></sup>

#### Install button: <kbd>[Install from GitHub](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Stack%20Exchange%2C%20%22View%20Vote%20totals%22%20without%201000%20rep.user.js)</kbd>

#### Code:

The code is [on GitHub, in the BrockA/SE-misc repository](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/blob/master/Stack%20Exchange%2C%20%22View%20Vote%20totals%22%20without%201000%20rep.user.js).

Post bug reports and pull requests there. <sup><sub>(Or below if you don't do GitHub.)</sub></sup>

Comment: I've updated my script to work with the new layout. So the latest version is not broken any more. The only functional difference between your and my script is that your script adds vote counts to all posts, whereas mine only shows it on the clicked post (which is closer to StackExchange's original functionality).

Comment: Thanks, @RobW, but another functional difference is that your script doesn't monitor for routine API feedback like `backoff`, low quota, or `error_id`.

Comment: @Welz, what screencap tool did you use?  (My old preferred one was borked by Firefox "Quantum".)

Comment: @BrockAdams I use [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) and I love it! It's open source and amazing for simple recordings. (It isn't necessarily  that great when it comes to massive recordings and very long/detailed ones - though I hardly ever need that.)